# @font-face does not work in iOS and Android

Tags: css, mobile, fonts, font-face

For one of my current web projects I'm using a *Candara* font, here's how I refer to it in my stylesheet:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Candara",sans-serif;
    src: url("../fonts/Candara_gdi.otf"); format('otf'),
         url("../fonts/Candara_gdi.woff"); format('woff'),
         url("../fonts/Candara.woff2"); format('woff2'),
         url("../fonts/Candara_gdi.eot"); format('eot'),
         url("../fonts/Candara_gdi.ttf"); format('truetype'),
         url("../fonts/Candara_gdi.svg#Candara-Regular"); format('svg');
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
}
```

After testing the site on mobile devices, I've noticed that *Candara* is not showing (the mobile devices render the fallback font, which is in this case 'sans-serif'). On the other hand, there's no problem with this font on all other desktop browsers, including the notorious IE family and Mozilla.
I'd like to mention that when I wanted to generate a webfont package [**here**](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator), there was a warning saying that Microsoft has blacklisted this font (see the screenshot of the warning):

[image]

Hence, I had to "manually" convert this font using some other online solutions. Any ideas on the issue and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the semi-colons after your url-declarations. A semi-colon ends the declaration for the `src`.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Candara",sans-serif;
        src: url("../fonts/Candara_gdi.otf") format('otf'),
             url("../fonts/Candara_gdi.woff") format('woff'),
             url("../fonts/Candara.woff2") format('woff2'),
             url("../fonts/Candara_gdi.eot") format('eot'),
             url("../fonts/Candara_gdi.ttf") format('truetype'),
             url("../fonts/Candara_gdi.svg#svgCandara_gdi") format('svg');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```